# Handlebars is not defined

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, referenceerror

I am new at JS and never tried Handlebars before.  I'm trying a very bare-bones example from a tutorial.  I have downloaded `handlebars-v4.0.5.js` from the Handlebars website and included it in my page, as follows, along with a template I precompiled, `name-table.js`.  I'm trying my god damned hardest to complete [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761) but I can't, because when I run the following code, I get `ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined` which I can't for the life of me understand, if the file I downloaded from Handebars' own site is in any way valid.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title>Test Page!</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function init() {
                document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', buttonClick, false);
            }
            function buttonClick() {
                var injection = Handlebars.templates['name-table'];
                document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = injection;
                console.log('hello, world.');
            }

            window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='button'>Button</button>
        <div id='content'></div>

        <script type='text/javascript' rel='js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' rel='js/name-table.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
The answer I marked solved the problem.  **Another error** appears in this code, and I want to let anyone reading this know that `var injection` as defined in this code is a function, not a string as I had thought.  This code will work if `rel` is changed to `src` as in the answer given, and if we use `document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = injection();` (note the parens).

Comment: You put the script that uses handlebars *above* the script tag that loads it.

Comment: Tried this and it did not solve the problem, as I would expect, because the script you reference that is "before" the handlebars definition doesn't run until after window.onload

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. Try replacing `Handlebars` with `window.Handlebars`. Although it shouldn't, you may be getting a strict mode exception for using an uninitialized var.

Comment: Tried your suggestion: "TypeError: window.Handlebars is undefined"

How does one strictly initialize a var that is supposed to be initialized in the Handlebars source obtained from their site?  I don't see this being done in any tutorial or SO Q&A.

Comment: Load the page. Open the console (ignoring the error for now). Type `window.Handlebars`. Hit return. Is it an object? That means your code is running before it loads. Is it undefined? That means there's a problem with the handlebars script.

Comment: It returns undefined.  Does this mean they're distributing a script that doesn't return a Handlebars var for people to work with, or am I using their script wrong, or using the wrong script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120333/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-fts-acer).

Comment: @fts_acer I've rolled back your edit, as it removes the root cause of your problem and thus invalidates the question. If you have a follow-up question, please [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you @Siguza that was a mistake on my part due to some confusion on my part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not loading in Handlebars (or your name-table script). You currently have the following markup:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' rel='js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' rel='js/name-table.js'></script>
```

You should be using the **src** attribute instead of the **rel** attribute for script tags.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/name-table.js'></script>
```

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) does not specify the rel attribute as a valid script tag attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Include this line:

```
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/handlebars.js"></script>
```

You are done.
Thanks.